# I can't deploy to my kubernetes cluster since I upgraded it to 1.3.0

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

My kubernetes cluster is hosted on Google Cloud on `europe-west1-d` region

My local setup have docker-engine@1.10 and kubectl@1.3.2

I managed to deploy without any issue when my cluster was on version 1.2.5

But since I upgraded to 1.3.0, I've got this:

`$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"3", GitVersion:"v1.3.2", GitCommit:"9bafa3400a77c14ee50782bb05f9efc5c91b3185", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-07-17T18:30:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
error: failed to negotiate an api version; server supports: map[], client supports: map[federation/v1beta1:{} apps/v1alpha1:{} authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1:{} authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1:{} autoscaling/v1:{} policy/v1alpha1:{} batch/v1:{} batch/v2alpha1:{} v1:{} rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1:{} componentconfig/v1alpha1:{} extensions/v1beta1:{}]`

Notice the: `server supports: map[]`

Comment: Are you sure you've properly updated to 1.3? What does `http://<kubernetes-master-ip>/version` show?

Comment: @PixelElephant I'm sure I did upgrade: http://imgur.com/a/SBi40

Although, when I try to go to `/version`: I got `Forbidden: "/version"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set a custom user name (other than admin) when you created your cluster? Kubernetes 1.3.0 on GKE has a known issue (see the [July 11, 2016 release notes](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes#july_11_2016)) where authorization fails if you try to authenticate using http basic auth. As described in the release note, you can use client certificate authentication until a fix is available.

Comment: I was using the username: `master`, and I thought it was the default one

Comment: Sorry about that. We should have a fix out shortly.

Comment: I'm still having this today. What information can I provide to help solve this?

Comment: Try running `gcloud auth application-default login` and resetting your application default credentials.